# How to invoke a SOAP UI request from an external system?

Tags: jenkins, soapui, soap-client

I have a requirement to upload few xml into my Siebel Application.
Since it is possible using SOAP UI software, I want to invoke the SOAP UI request using command line or using Linux terminal ?

Note: By External System I mean using command line or Linux terminal.

Comment: hi, do you mean calling a remote system in a soap ui groovy step or remotely call soapui on a remote system ?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI can be invoked from a commandline. You just need a Java Runtime Environment in order to do so.

In a windows commandline prompt, you just use the testrunner.bat

Running on Linux, you will need to adjust the commands accordingly, but it is absolutely doable.